# Position a vertical list in a div to center of said DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm running into a bit of a problem with some code I'm working on. I want the list in the menu to always be vertically centered in relation to the menu div. I've tried various solutions found here but the list always end up at the top of the div. Can it be done? Ideally it must work even if the does not have a fixed height.

and here's the CSS:

Comment: `I've tried various solutions found here` please share one of them with us, so we can help getting it to work. I'm asking that because there are couple of methods which may or may not fit your needs.

Comment: This is my solution. Check it if it fits http://jsfiddle.net/pwk2ws7x/ I'll post an answer later if it does. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using `line-height` to achieve this (if the menu is the only thing within the div).

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/86f94kfu/1/)

---

For example: Add a height of 200px to `#menu`, and add a line-height of 200px to `#menu ul`

Answer (score 1):

you can try converting ul and li elements to display as inline-block elements. And set vertical alignment to middle

```
ul, li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A common technique is to use the `display: table;` for the parent and `display: table-cell;` for the child. Then you can apply `vertical-align: middle;` to the child.

Here's a [code example](http://codepen.io/dugweb/pen/xGpwH)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider applying `display: flex;` to `#menu`.

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gzgbx9c/)

Comment: That would be my last choice in real world (due to lack of browser compatibility)